# After upgrading from Solr 3.5 to Solr 4.7 some queries return error

Tags: solr, solr4

The following query was work fine in Solr 3.5:

```
http://localhost:6060/solr/newsarchive/select/?q=WebSite:www.shorouknews.com&sort=Date%20desc&version=2.2&start=&rows=10&indent=on&wt=json
```

However, it generates the following error with Solr 4.7. I tried to update `<luceneMatchVersion>LUCENE_35</luceneMatchVersion>`
 and I set it to LUCENE_40 but the error is still exist. Does it an issue of the schema.xml? or Issue in the index? However, there are other simple queries works fine such as `http://localhost:8983/solr/newsarchive4/select?q=%D9%85%D8%B5%D8%B1&wt=json&indent=true`

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":500,
    "QTime":35,
    "params":{
      "sort":"Date desc",
      "indent":"on",
      "start":"",
      "q":"WebSite:www.shorouknews.com",
      "wt":"json",
      "rows":"10",
      "version":"2.2"}},
  "error":{
    "msg":"For input string: \"\"",
    "trace":"java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: \"\"\r\n\tat java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.search.QParser.getSort(QParser.java:244)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.prepare(QueryComponent.java:151)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:196)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:135)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1916)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:768)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:415)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:205)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:455)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1075)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:384)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1009)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:368)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:942)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1004)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:640)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)\r\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)\r\n",
    "code":500}}
```

**EDIT**

> I noticed that `start=` in the query is not defined i.e `&start=&`, other versions of Solr regarded
>   it equals to 0 but 4.7 regarded it unknown. The question becomes, How
>   could I make Solr assign 0 to undefined `start`?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's not undefined, it's actually present in the URL (which is why you're getting the error - you're trying to set it to an empty string). You could try to supply it as an default to the SearchHandler, but I'm not sure if that will actually help, since as mentioned, the value is actually present. It's just empty.

```xml
<lst name="defaults">
    <int name="start">0</int>
</lst>
```

You'd be better off fixing the reason why you're sending an empty `start=` parameter instead, or possibly, rewriting it in your container before the query reaches Solr. How you do that depends on which application container you're using.

Comment: Under which defaults? For example, there is `<requestHandler name="standard" ...`,`<requestHandler name="dismax" `, and so on.

Comment: Depends on which one you're accessing.